# Removing locks on files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-unlocking

I need to modify a file that is locked by a process. How can I find the responsible process and release its lock? I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: i suppose you mean it is locked, not UNlocked :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)** - It is a free tool to delete files blocked by something you do not know.

[image]

[image]

*LockHunter is freeware.*

Answer (score 18):

You can use  SysInternals (owned by Microsoft) free tool [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to unlock a file handle.

Just use the **Find** menu to search for the file that is locked.  This will show which process has the lock on the file.  If you can't get the process to release the lock by shutting it down safely, you can forcefully release the lock by double clicking the search result to show the file in the main Process Explorer window.  Then right-click the file and select **Close Handle**

Comment: I never noticed the "Find"menu, very helpful!